# Mongo driver data distribution awareness

Tags: mongodb

I read various mongodb manuals (e.g. [1]) and *MongoDB Architecture Guide* and as far as got *mongos* proxy is needed to setup sharded cluster. And the question is how mongodb justifies an additional network hop needed when dispatching a request to a sharded cluster?

In contrast, Cassandra client drivers can support a *TokenAwarePolicy* [2] routing policy and send requests directly to a node containing data.

[1] https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/

[2] https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.6/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/TokenAwarePolicy.html